# Como insertar información de varios items en un registro, sistema de facturación

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de la U y me pidieron un sistema de facturación en inventario, y se supone que cualquier cliente puede comprar varios productos al tiempo, pero no entiendo como hacer para poner todos los productos y que se deben registrar en una soa factura, aqui esta el insert que uso para simular que comprar un solo producto

```
insert into factura (identificacion, nombrecp,
                     fecha, iva, tipo, vtotal, descripcion,
                     subtotal, estado) values ('1140884366',
                     'Edward Sierra', '13/11/2018', 30040, 'FV',
                     100000, 'PRUEBA', 90000, 'activo');
```

aqui la imagen de como esta el formato para agregar los productos:

[image: formato de venta o compra]

que me recomiendan?

Comment: Comunmente no insertas varios productos o artículos en un solo registro. Usualmente creas una tabla de detalle de factura e insertas un artículo en cada registro de esa tabla. La tabla de factura tiene una relación de 1 a N con la tabla de detalle de factura.

Answer (score 1):

La idea es como dice el primer comentario. Tenes que tener una clase factura que posea el encabezado de la factura (Fecha, Cliente, Numero de factura) y una clase DetalleDeFactura que posea los distintos articulos que se encuentran en la factura. Cabe mencionar que si el precio del producto se encuentra en el articulo, en ese caso debes guardar el precio por separado al producto ya que si en algun momento le cambias el precio al articulo. Todas las facturas que realizaste con el precio anterior se actualizaran al precio nuevo. Es un error muy normal cuando uno recien comienza en esto. PAra eso debes guardar el precio del producto separado del producto en si
Algo asi seria[image: UML Factura]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Previo a este form necesitarías tener una tabla en la bd con los datos del cliente, de esa forma solo tendrias q seleccionar el cliente y llenar los label con los datos de el, previamente guardado. al igual que los datos de los productos.

Para registrar los productos, como te menciono @jachguate, debes hacerlo uno a uno en una tabla de detalle de factura, la cual puedes mostrar mediante un [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) e ir refrescando con cada insert

Comment: esto parece mas un comentario pues le dices que hacer pero no como, revisa [answer] las respuestas reciben mejor puntaje siempre que incluyan código